# try to call drawRect of subView for changing it but get runtime error

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to draw some lines after some events happened on my main View but I'll get some runtime error says :

> -[subView setNeedsDisplay:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b03460 2011-11-09 18:32:33.209 testSubView[53131:40b] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[subView setNeedsDisplay:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b03460'

and this is what I have done :

create a subview.h/m then import subview.h inside my viewcontroller

and this is my viewcontroller code :

```
subView * sb;
-(void) viewDidLoad
{

    CGRect subviewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320);
    sb = [[[subView alloc] initWithFrame:subviewRect] retain];
    [sb setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:sb];

}

-(IBAction) slidingN : (UISlider *) sender
{
    NSLog(@"slider called");
    NSLog(@"%d" , (int)sliderN.value);
    [sb setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

please let me know what exactly my problem is.

Comment: Did you set UIView as subViews superclass.

Comment: yes if this is what you mean : @interface subView : UIView {...}

Answer (score 1):

UIView's `-setNeedsDisplay` doesn't take a parameter. You're thinking of the NSView version.

Change your code to:

```
[sb setNeedsDisplay];
```